# Charge distribution which yields harmonic oscillation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, harmonic-oscillator

Perhaps this is more of a math question, or I may be using the wrong tools for a given problem. Any insight would be helpful.

> **Question**
>
> Assume J.J. Thomson's "plum-pudding" model of the atom. Now take the hydrogen atom; we have a positive charge +e distributed over a sphere with radius $10^{-8}$cm. The electron is a point charge -e.  Question: How should the positive charge be distributed over the sphere so as to lead to harmonic oscillations of the electron?
>
> Note, we may neglect all mechanical interactions and the magnetic field of the moving electron.

**Solution Attempt**

Harmonic oscillations, $\vec{F} = -k_{s} \vec{x}$

Coulomb force, $\vec{F} = k \frac{q_{1} q_{2}}{r^{2}} \hat{r}_{1,2}$

Define a spherical coordinate system, $(r,\theta,\psi)$ with radius r, angle $\theta$ on the x-y axis, and angle $\psi$ from the z axis. Further:
\begin{align}
 r&\in [-\infty, \infty] \\   \theta &\in [0, \pi) \\ \psi &\in[0,\pi)
\end{align}
[Note that I've limited the range of $\theta$ in favor of a +/- $r$]

Let the charge density of the sphere at a given coordinate be represented by $\rho(r',\theta',\psi')$ [C/m$^{3}$]. The position of the electron is represented by $(r,\theta,\psi)$.

Assume harmonic oscillations will occur with the electron traveling along an axis through the center of the sphere. Rewrite harmonic oscillation equation $\vec{F} = -k_{s} \vec{r}$ (note the convenience of allowing negative $\vec{r}$). Set equal to force on electron due to $\rho$:
\begin{align}
F_{-e} &= -k_{s} r = \int -k e \frac{\rho(r',\theta',\psi')}{R^2} dV \\
           \text{where  }
          R^2 &= r^2 + r'^2 - 2rr'(\cos\theta \cos\theta' \sin\psi \sin\psi' + \sin\theta \sin\theta' \sin\psi \sin\psi' + \cos\psi \cos\psi')
\end{align}

Expanding:
\begin{align}
\frac{k_{s}}{k e} r = \int_0^\pi\int_0^\pi\int_0^{10^{-10}} \frac{\rho(r',\theta',\psi')}{R^2} r'^2 \sin\psi' dr' d\theta' d\psi'
\end{align}

**Simplification Attempt**

From this point one needs to solve for $\rho(r',\theta',\psi')$, which I've made little headway in. By symmetry, we know $\rho(r',\theta',\psi')$ will really only depend on r', so $\rho(r',\theta',\psi') = \rho(r')$.

I've tried some simplifying assumptions to get started. In particular assuming the electron is only on the x-axis and thus simplifying the term $R^2$ by asserting $\psi,\theta = 0$. Now $R^2 = r^2 + r'^2 - 2rr'\cos\psi'$.

Now I can write:
\begin{align}
\frac{k_{s}}{k e} r &= \int_0^\pi\int_0^\pi\int_0^{10^{-10}} \frac{\rho(r')}{r^2 + r'^2 - 2rr'\cos\psi'} r'^2 \sin\psi' dr' d\theta' d\psi' \\
   &= \pi\int_0^{10^{-10}}\int_0^\pi \frac{\rho(r')r'^2 \sin\psi'}{r^2 + r'^2 - 2rr'\cos\psi'}d\psi' dr'
\end{align}
From here I would like to integrate with respect to $\psi'$ then (hopefully) the form of $\rho(r')$ may become more apparent. I have not been able to do this. Any suggestions, corrections, or alternative approaches would be very helpful. Thank you!

Comment: There is a lot to digest here.  I would suggest specifically pointing to your issue and why it deviates from your expectation or the correct answer.  For instance, I think that the indefinite integral
$$
\int \ dx \ \frac{ A \sin{x} }{ B + C \cos{x} } = - \frac{ A \ln{\left( B + C \cos{x} \right)} }{ C } + E
$$
is perfectly integrable (e.g., _Mathematica_ had no problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's much easier than that. You know what the electric field needs to be,
$$
\mathbf E(\mathbf r) = -k\mathbf r,
$$
and Gauss's law tells you how to get the charge density from the electric field,
$$
\nabla \cdot \mathbf E = \rho/\varepsilon_0.
$$
That is all you need, essentially, though you do need to impose (i) a finite region, so you'll have a finite amount of charge, and (ii) isotropy, so that the solution will be the unique one that respects the symmetry of the charge distribution.

Comment: And/or one remembers doing the hole-through-the-earth problem.